# Is it “James and Paul come” or “James and Paul comes”?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is the correct way of writing:

> As an appointment, James and Paul **comes** tomorrow.

Or

> As on appointment, James and Paul **come** tomorrow.

I would also like to know why.

Comment: What is the "as an appointment" part supposed to mean? It makes no sense. "As on appointment" even less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As appointed, James and Paul come tomorrow.*

The verb has to agree with the subject in person and number. The subject of the sentence is *James and Paul*. The person is third and the number is plural. The third person plural form of the present tense of *to come* is ***come*** (*comes* is the third person singular).

Note that I changed the introductory adverbial phrase. *As on appointment* is not an aceptable idomatic phrase in US English (nor British, I believe).

You also could say *As per their appointment*, but that wouold be somewhat stilted. Probably *As scheduled* would be even better.

Comment: Your answer is helpful.